# Any differences between ～に志願する and　～を志願する?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-を

I thought に was the universal particle with 志願, but I have seen を used quite commonly too and I wonder if there are some nuances in meaning.

> 死刑を志願した男

> 大学に志願する
> 大学を志願する
> 大学に入学を志願する.

> 軍隊に志願する
> 兵役を志願する
> 特攻隊に志願する

> 管理職に志願した男
> 看護婦を志願する

> 田舎教師（1909）〈田山花袋〉六「小島は第一を志願するらしい」 〔嵆康‐与山巨源絶交書〕<sup>1</sup>  ([精選版 日本国語大辞典](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BF%97%E9%A1%98-517475))

They don't appear to differ in meaning.

---

1. I am not quite sure about this entry. So it is from a work titled 田舎教師 by 田山花袋. But what is 〔嵆康‐与山巨源絶交書〕?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xに志願する and Xを志願する are sometimes interchangeable, but I feel the latter has a stronger implication of *choosing or asking for* X from multiple options. Less commonly, Xを志願する can mean just "to make up one's mind to become X" without explicit request/application to some authority (を志望する is more common in this sense, though). I don't know why but it may because it's close to を選ぶ or を志望する.

- 死刑を志願する
  to ask for (one's own) death penalty (instead of life imprisonment)
  <sub>(You cannot say 死刑に志願する because 死刑 is not a job/role.)</sub>
- 落語家に弟子入りを志願する
  to ask a rakugo performer for an apprenticeship
  <sub>(You cannot say 弟子入りに志願する because it's not a job/role.)</sub>
- 政治家を志願する
  to make up one's mind to become a politician
  <sub>(政治家 is a job name, but 政治家に志願する does not make sense because no authority can grant this job to you.)</sub>
- 看護師を志願する
  to apply for the job as a nurse (rather than something else) / to make up one's mind to become a nurse
  <sub>(This makes sense only when there are multiple options.)</sub>
- 小島は第一を志願するらしい。
  Looks like Kojima will *rather* apply for Dai-ichi (School).
  <sub>(This is almost synonymous with 第一に志願するらしい.)</sub>